# Visual Studio меняет поток при отладке и теряются данные

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, отладка

Пишу на mvc3. Передаю данные из представления в контроллер (используя форму, методом POST). В контроллере стоит у меня точка останова. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку "След. шаг"(при отладке) он переходит к следующему шагу но потом сразу перескакивает обратно. Приходится нажимать на кнопку два раза, что бы VS выполнил одну операцию. Текст который выдает при этом VS на скринах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio отлаживает приложение целиком. Если вам в приложение пришло два запроса - они будут выполняться в двух разных потоках. Оба потока попадут на ваш breakpoint. И студия будет прыгать между ними при отладке туда-сюда.

Хотите удобной пошаговой отладки - сделайте так, чтобы приходил ровно один поток (например, запишите запрос fiddler-ом, и проигрывайте его). Или, если совсем не получается избежать двух запросов, поставьте на паузу все остальные потоки в Debug / Window / Threads.

Comment: а почему приходят два запроса? У меня один только должен идти.

Comment: @Vivus, например шлешь несколько через какое-то время, приложение открыто в нескольких вкладках/браузерах

Comment: Просто до этого такого не было. А щас появилось. И изменений нет, которые могли бы повлиять на это. Я вообще этот контроллер не трогал.

Comment: @Vivus без разницы, трогали вы контроллер или нет. У вас приходит на него из браузера два запроса одновременно. Можно проверить в том же Debug / Windows / Threads. Код контроллера тут ни при чем - это не от него зависит, а от кода на странице, который отправляет запрос.